# Is it recommended to combine multiple "related" features into one vector in the scenario below?

Tags: machine-learning, vector, data-science, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I am a beginner/novice at "practical" machine learning.

I have compiled a very large data set to create a binary classification machine learning model.  The data set has over 80 columns but I'm trying to shrink that column list down.  I've run the data through multiple algorithms (Decition Tree, Random Forest, Gradient Boosting); used various hyper-parameter tuning; and analyzed multiple permutation feature importance (PFI) results to see what features need to be removed.  So far, my accuracy (and other metrics such as F1-score, precision, recall) is hovering anywhere between 70 and 80%.  My question is this:

If I have a subset of 2-4 columns whose data is not only related, but dependent on each other
i.e.
- colA won't make much sense without also looking and using colB, colC, etc
- colA won't make much sense without adding/subtracting/dividing with colB

Is it possible/recommended to combine these few columns into a vector or another feature?

For example, colA plotted as a time series would make a nice non-linear curved line. colB plotted as a time series would also make a nice non-linear curved line.  However, looking at each of these lines won't make much sense until you look at where they intersect (which happens again and again).  So you can see here that the distance between any two points (colA, colB) is really important.

BUT BUT when I include a colC which is the result of difference between colA and colC, the PFI analysis kicks colC back as a bad feature that lowers accuracy, etc.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated and thank you all in advance for your help.

If you need me to provide any more info/example, let me know.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how your data looks. Might want to see some example/matrise for people to answer better :)

If you are sure you want to remove features , have you tried Lasso? With L1 regularization some features gets completely ignored . set alpha low and see what happenes?

Ex: lasso001 = Lasso(alpha=0.01, max_iter= 10000).fit(X_train, y_train)....and so on. 
print output with n of features . If you want it to use more features, set alpha lower. just be aware of overfitting...
you can also "tune" the parameter in LogisticRegression and LinearSVM. ( C).